# Moving element from one position to another

Tags: jquery, html

In a container I have four rows. Each with a different number of columns. Whenever I click on each row it should move to its next row. However on clicking the final row (any row which comes to the final position) it should move to the first row.

I tried the `insertAfter()` method in jQuery but I was not able to move the final row. Please suggest me best way to  move the final row.

I have the current setup in my page:

```
$(".row").each(function() {
  $(this).insertAfter($(this).next());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `next()` returns an element. If it doesn't, use the first. Something like this:

```
$(".row").each(function() {
  var $row = $(this);
  var $target = $row.next();
  if (!$target.length)
    $target = $row.siblings().first();

  $row.insertAfter($target);
});
```

It's possible you can simplify the `siblings().first()` call, but that would depend on how your HTML is structured.